# what does " something makes the pain worth it " mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

I mean in this sentence

> Glad you could enjoy that. Really makes the pain worth it.

What does it mean?

Comment: I'm thinking this would have probably been better suited for [ell.SE]; perhaps you might want to ask your next question there. You might consider adding a little more context next time, too, like where you saw or heard the quote. Some expressions can mean something entirely different depending on the setting and context. "Flying low" might mean one thing to an aviator, but it can be used metaphorically, and has a slang meaning as well. It's hard to say what something means when you present it all by itself.

Answer (score 4):

What is says.

> It was painful to produce/create whatever you are enjoying and to see you happy with the product/experience made the pain easier to take.

Depending on context it could be meant sarcastically.

If you are enjoying something that the producer does not feel you deserve to enjoy, he could sarcastically say the same.

Comment: Instead of "produce," one could say "set up," and instead of "product," one could say "experience." Thus, an alternate interpretation might be: _It was painful to set up whatever you are enjoying, and to see you happy with the experience made the pain easier to take._ I'm thinking of a wedding, e.g. Same idea, just a slightly different take on it.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this